# Alpha value of 3d chart's rotation ? where is the center?

Tags: highcharts, draggable

My chart:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-scatter-draggable/

```
   beta:
```

I think that the value "beta" of 3d draggable scatter chart, is at half of xAxis (so at the half of "max-width")..

```
   alpha:
```

but alpha ? where is the center of rotation for Alpha ?

I ask you this, because i would like to add an image that rotates together the chart, when i rotate the chart. 
And to transform the image i must to know many things as Alpha and beta...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beta/alpha are rotation angles by x / y axis.

Docs:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.options3d.alpha
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.options3d.beta

Comment: Sebastian, do you know the coordinates of Alpha ? Alpha is at the center of chart ?? I understood (maybe) beta, but no Alpha.... Can you help me ?

Comment: The point of angles are correct with axis position, then there are transleted after rotation.